# Angular routing structure with nested child components

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

My **Angular** web panel has a **routing ramification** like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, data: { },
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'user', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'user', component: UserComponent, data: { },
        children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'products', pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent, data: { }, 
            children: [
              { 
                path: ':id', component: ProductDetail, data: { } 
              },
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

**HomeComponent** e **UserComponent** are just **router-outlet for childs**.

**ProductsComponent** has a **list of product**.

**ProductDetail** component **don't appear** because his father **ProductsComponent** **don't have a "router-outlet"** tag in his html.

How the routing structure should be, in order to have, a father with the list of products, and the child with the product detail?

Set both **ProductsComponent** and **ProductDetail** as child of **UserComponent** resolve the problem, but create an ugly structure in my breadcrumb (*home > user > list* and *home > user > detail*)

My goal is to have a breadcrumb with a good components structure. 
Like home > user > list > detail.

Comment: You dont' need more than one router-outlet unless you doing auxillary routes which doesn't look like you are.

Comment: Maybe I write down the code above in a non comprensive way, Let's say I have this routing:

   path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
   children: [
       { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent },
       { path: 'products/:id', component: ProductDetail }
   ]

List and Detail are brothers, should be better set Detail as child of List?

Answer (score 2):

I'm on my phone so forgive any formatting errors, I'll edit this later.

If I understood correctly, you should be able to achieve what you want by using the following route configuration:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, data: { },
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'user', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'user', component: UserComponent, data: { },
        children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'products', pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent, data: { }}, 
{path: 'products/:id', component: ProductDetail, data: { }} 
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

You don't need to nest components in order to have a "nice" route, you can create it in the `path` property.

Moreover, if your HomeComponent and UserComponent are just router-outlets, you could probably simplify everything to

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home/user/products', component: ProductsComponent, data: { }}, 
    {path: 'home/user/products/:id', component: ProductDetail, data: { }} 
];
```

And then add the correct redirectTo clause.